# CKEditor gem not working in production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor

I'm using the CKEditor gem (v 4.0.7.2) with my Rails 4 app.  It works fine in development, but as soon as I switch the server to production mode, I get the following JavaScript error in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'langEntries' of null`.  Additionally, some CKEditor dialogs no longer show up.

What changed in the JavaScript between dev and production?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500525/ckeditor-4-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-langentries-of-null see the comments.

Comment: Interestingly, the solution offered by @Mavis does fix the `langEntries` error, but my page is still missing some functionality (that it has in development mode).  This functionality all exists in app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/plugins/.  Any ideas as to why this dir is a problem in dev mode?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't begin to guess without _some_ specific information to go off of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being a difference between the development and production environments' load order of JavaScript files (production is lexigraphic and development is...not...).  By replacing a `require_tree` in the Gemfile with a `require` for each file **and putting the files in the order they need to load**, the problem was resolved.

Comment: But what's the order ? Which file needs to be loaded after / before ?